# How to call a function in one html page in another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have 2 pages. one.html and two.html

The first html page contains a script tag with a java script function modify(d).In two.html i want to call this same function instead of retyping it again.How can i do this? Do i need to create a link between the pages? if yes, How?

I have tried using  in the second file. But i keep getting the error: "modify(d) not defined" in the console.

Both of the files are placed next to each other in my folder structure so the path should be correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create a JS file and reference this file in both HTML documents like `<script src="path/some.js"></script>`

Comment: It is also possible to call a function from another page by loading it [in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop inline scripts (and it goes for inline styles too) and do like this, where you store functions (and rules) in a file of its own, you will be able to reuse it (them) like shown in below sample

File: one.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page One</title>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    Page one content  
</body>
</html>
```

File: two.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page two</title>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    Page two content  
</body>
</html>
```

File: style.css

```
body {
  background: url(../images/bkg.png);
}
```

File: script.js

```
function modify(d) {
  ....
}
```

And have your files located like this in your folder

```
/www/one.html
/www/two.html
/www/js/script.js
/www/css/style.css
/www/images/bkg.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your JavaScript script tag content into its own file and include that script in both HTML pages, so:

- create a file somewhere in your folder structure (you can put it in the same path as your HTML files for ease at the moment) let's say it's called my script.js
- in each one of your HTML files you can include your script using script tags:

  ```
  <script src="./script.js"/>
  ```

You can include the script tag in the `<head>` of your HTML files *or* as the last element within the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the JS in its own file and reference it from both HTML file. Below is a pseudo code to explain better.

**script.js**

```
$('.box').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Box has been logged!');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div
```

**other.html**

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of External Javascript. Refer the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp).
Using this, create a single Javascipt file and put the `modify()` method into it. Now load the javascript on both the forms.(i.e one.html and two.html)