# Is it possible to go to another page and call Javascript function after clicking button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, href

My first post here :)

Hello everyone,

I have two .htmls, first one is named a.html, and second one is named b.html. I want to go to b.html and call there a function after button on a.html is clicked. The function i would like to run is stored locally in b.html.

Here's the preview of what i'm trying to achieve:

`<button type="button" id="rezerwacjawarriors" onclick="location.href='rezerwacja.html' AND CALL FUNCTION ON B.HTML STORED IN B.HTML AFTER LOADING PAGE;">Rezerwacja</button>`

Is it even possible to do it like this?

Function i would like to call on b.html make specific div appear.

English is not my native language so im sorry for any misunderstandings and mistakes.

Thanks for help. =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load Does this help?

Comment: The thing is i want to run function on b.html automatically only when button on a.html is clicked, not every single time the b.html is loaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946465/how-to-call-a-function-in-one-html-page-in-another-html-page This might help and welcome to StackOverflow!!

Comment: @Anglesvar the question you commented is different than this question. The question you commented about is about reusing code, and this question is about calling a function in another page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) so that `b.html` knows to call the function on load.

Page a script

```js
// ... on click
window.location.replace('b.html?callFunction=specialFunction')
```

Page b script

```js
if (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('callFunction') === 'specialFunction') {
 // Call function or do whatever
}
```

You can have different actions based on different values of `callFunction` (or any query string key you choose)
[Here is a link to a repl which does this](https://replit.com/@Programmerraj/call-function-in-other-page#scriptA.js).

If you don't like the query parameters at the end of the url, you can remove them - [Remove URL parameters without refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753052/remove-url-parameters-without-refreshing-page).